# Showing if scalar product of vectors is 1 then they are the same quantum state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation, quantum-information

How do you show that if $|\langle \psi|\phi\rangle| = 1$, then $\phi$ and $\psi$, both of dimension $d$, represent the same quantum state?
(Same quantum state iff there exists a $\theta$ s.t. $|\psi\rangle = e^{i\theta}|\phi\rangle$)

I've tried doing given
$|\langle \psi|\phi\rangle| = 1$

$$\Leftrightarrow \left|\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}{\psi_{k}\phi_{k}}\right| = 1$$

$$\Leftrightarrow \left|\exp(i\theta)\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}{\psi_{k}\phi_{k}}\right| = 1   $$
for any $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, but couldn't go much further.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: By "same quantum state" do you mean $\psi = \alpha \phi$ with $|\alpha | = 1$ ?

Comment: @KeithMcClary yes, thats what I mean. Thank you for pointing it out, I have edited the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: use [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

> As quantum states are normalized, we have
>  $$|\langle \psi | \phi \rangle|^2 = 1 = \langle \psi | \psi \rangle \langle \phi | \phi \rangle,$$
>  so $\phi$ and $\psi$ are linearly dependent. Neither of them is zero, hence one must be a scalar multiple of the other. This scalar is in $U(1)$, as both states have magnitude $1$.

Comment: How does $⟨ψ|ϕ⟩|^{2}=1=⟨ψ|ψ⟩⟨ϕ|ϕ⟩ $ imply linear dependence?

Comment: This is a corollary of C–S inequality